# Dynamic bootstrap cards with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop, while-loop

I have here a json file and this content should get rendered inside of bootstrap cards.

```
[{
    "scripts": {
        "web3py": [
            {
                "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/sendetherweb3py.png",
                "scriptName": "send Native",
                "description": "send native with web3py",
                "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
            },
            {
                "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/sendtokenweb3py.png",
                "scriptName": "send token",
                "description": "send erc20 token with web3py",
                "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
            },
            {
                "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/swapnativeweb3py.png",
                "scriptName": "swap native token dex",
                "description": "swap eth for erc20 token",
                "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
            },
            {
                "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/swaptokenweb3py.png",
                "scriptName": "swap erc20 token on dex",
                "description": "swap erc20 token with erc20 token",
                "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "web3js": [
            {
                "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/swaptokenethers.png",
                "scriptName": "swap token on dex",
                "description": "swap erc20 token with token on a dex",
                "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
            },
            {
                "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/swapnativeethers.png",
                "scriptName": "swap native",
                "description": "swap native for token on dex",
                "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
            },
            {
                "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/sendtokenethers.png",
                "scriptName": "send ERC20 token",
                "description": "send erc20 token with ethers",
                "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
            },
            {
                "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/sendnativeethers.png",
                "scriptName": "send native",
                "description": "send Native ETH with ethers",
                "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

Inside scripts I have 2 categories, web3py and web3js with 4 items in it.
Now i want to render web3py inside a row that than contains 4 cards and another row web3js that contains also 4 cards.

How can I render bootstrap cards in Javscript based on the content from my json file?

I want to do this dynamically so in case i add more items to web3py or web3js, i want the cards to be created dynamically.

So what would be the best way to create those 4 cards inside a row using javascript?

Card looks like this

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src=${thumbnail} class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${scriptName}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">${description}</p>
    <a href=${link} class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This here is my Javascript file

```
async function getScript(){
    const scripts = await fetch('./scripts.json')
    const response = await scripts.json()
    //console.log(response[0])
    const scripta = response[0]['scripts']['web3py']
    const image = response[0]['scripts']['web3py'][0]['thumbnail']
   
    const title = response[0]['scripts']['web3py'][0]['scriptName']
    const description = response[0]['scripts']['web3py'][0]['description']
    console.log(title)


    let content = '';

scripta.forEach(p => {
  content += `
    <div id="keyBoard" class="col-md-4 mt-2">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img src="${image}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="keyboard">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title" id="itemName">${title}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text" id="itemDesc">${description}</p>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addCart">Add to cart</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
  `
});

document.querySelector("#shop").innerHTML = content;
    

}
getScript()
```

the problem is that this function prints out the 1st item 4 times in 1 row instead of the 1 item each in 1 row

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the JSON data using a nested loop and then use an empty variable to build the HTML string. Then insert that HTML using ***insertAdjacentHTML***. Additional comments within the code breaking down what each line is doing.

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main')
// an empty variable to hold the card as it is built within a for loop
const jsonObj = [{
  "scripts": {
    "web3py": [{
        "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/sendetherweb3py.png",
        "scriptName": "send Native",
        "description": "send native with web3py",
        "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      },
      {
        "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/sendtokenweb3py.png",
        "scriptName": "send token",
        "description": "send erc20 token with web3py",
        "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      },
      {
        "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/swapnativeweb3py.png",
        "scriptName": "swap native token dex",
        "description": "swap eth for erc20 token",
        "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      },
      {
        "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/swaptokenweb3py.png",
        "scriptName": "swap erc20 token on dex",
        "description": "swap erc20 token with erc20 token",
        "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "web3js": [{
        "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/swaptokenethers.png",
        "scriptName": "swap token on dex",
        "description": "swap erc20 token with token on a dex",
        "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      },
      {
        "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/swapnativeethers.png",
        "scriptName": "swap native",
        "description": "swap native for token on dex",
        "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      },
      {
        "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/sendtokenethers.png",
        "scriptName": "send ERC20 token",
        "description": "send erc20 token with ethers",
        "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      },
      {
        "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/sendnativeethers.png",
        "scriptName": "send native",
        "description": "send Native ETH with ethers",
        "link": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}]

// define the object
const scripts = jsonObj[0]['scripts']
// define an output variable to hold HTML
let output = ''
// loop over the two nested arrays
for (let objs in scripts) {
  // set first row
  output += '<div class="d-flex">'
  // get data from first array of objects
  scripts[objs].forEach(item => {  
     output += `
     <div class="card ${objs}" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src=${item["thumbnail"]} class="card-img-top col-sm flex-row" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body col-sm">
        <h5 class="card-title">${item["scriptName"]}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${item["description"]}</p>
        <a href=${item["link"]} class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>`
  })
  // close the row
  output += '</div>'
}

// insert the HTML using .insertAdjacentHTML
main.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', output)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```